# How to dynamically place absolute position to fit parent?

Tags: css, grid

Okay, its kinda difficult to explain what I'm looking for, but you know when you have a dropdown menu and when the dropdown content doesnt fit on the screen the dropdown menu changes direction or moves a little bit to fit?

I have a component which constains a dropdown with absolute positioning and a display grid with 3 columns. It works great until I get to the right side of the screen, then it gets squished and overflows to the right, like this:

[image: See how the content is being squished]

What I would like to happen is this:

[image: See how its not being squished]

In this case I just manually set the right:0 on the dropdown element, but since it is a component I would like to keep it generalized and for it to automatically have a logic like this: If it is overflowing to the right, then set right:0.

Sure that should be extendable in each and every direction as well (even though I can't imagine much use cases there), or, in general terms: "If it would overflow to the right/left/top/botton, then set (each which overflows) right/left/top/bottom: 0.

Is this even possible with only css?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this on your CSS

```
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  right: 0;
}

.dropdown.is-open {
  transform: none;
}
```

Maybe it will work

Comment: That unfortunately doesnt address the issue, I just have "dropdown" when it is opened, and I want for it to detect when there's enough space or not, and in this case move.